# SQL-Server common problem - Retrieve ID just inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've looked at some other questions, they seem to be unrelated to SQL-Server.

Given the simple example query:

```
INSERT INTO tblComments (comment, user) VALUES ('lol', 'Guest')
```

Now suppose after the new user is created I need to insert some more data in other tables that require the last entered ID, I would do:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM tblComments ORDER BY ID DESC
```

To retreive the last entered ID, (hoping) that no queries have executed in the meantime, and that the returned ID is indeed for the value of the previous query.

I do keep my tables normalised, however I sometimes run into the situation where the inserted value may not necesserially be unique, so how can I guarantee the returned ID is the last one inserted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach is subject to a race condition.

Instead, use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx):

```
select scope_identity()
```

Comment: If you put both queries in the same transaction, you should be fairly certain that it's the right id.

Comment: A race condition or race hazard is a flaw in an electronic system or process whereby the output and/or result of the process is unexpectedly and critically dependent on the sequence or timing of other events. The term originates with the idea of two signals racing each other to influence the output first. (Wikipedia)

Comment: @Martin Smith: But nevertheless the question involves ordering the ID's indicating that they are in fact numbers and not guids.

Comment: @Martin - Well spotted. In that case `scope_identity` would be the way ahead! +1

Comment: Sorry, tag is slightly wrong, I tagged uniqueidentifier meaning a unique identity for a record.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @RedFilter's suggestion you should also look at:

1. @@IDENTITY if you want the last
   identity that was inserted into any
   table in the current session even if the insert wasn't done
   in the current scope.
2. IDENT_CURRENT to get the last
   identity inserted in a specific table
   regardless of session or scope.

In your case SCOPE_IDENTITY is probably the way to go unless you want to get that identity even if the it is inserted in a different session or scope.

And just to be clear SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the last identity inserted into any table in the current session and scope.